# Как из HTML тега вытащить текст в переменную angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular

Хочу сделать простую программу с тегом `<textarea>`.

Пользователь пишет текст, и выводится `<p>"Пользователь написал: {{text}}" </p>`

Как мне передать  текст из html тега в стринговую  переменную ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Модуль:

```
// app.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Компонент:

```
// app.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
    public text: string = null;
}
```

Шаблон:

```
// app.component.html

<textarea [(ngModel)]="text"></textarea>
<p>Пользователь написал {{ text }}</p>
```

Comment: большое спасибо!